# datatables: Length filter loses prepended custom filter value

Tags: jquery, datatables

[here is my example](http://live.datatables.net/laxinabe/13/edit)

to recreate:

1. open your network panel in firebug or chrome to see the requests
2. change the custom filter #fundraiser_id, note that the header form_data shows the new selection you have made (i_fundraiser)
3. change the length filter to any new value

by looking at the header form_data, you will now see that the parameter has returned to its defaulted value

the offender appears to be 
.prependTo("#example_length")

by commenting that out, it works fine

Im not sure whats going on here, I attempted to add the prepend to the table by drawCallback method, but the same problem exists

```
"drawCallback": function( settings ) {
  $("#fr_dd")
      .prependTo("#example_length")
      .removeClass('hide');
},
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to modify area that DataTables manipulates by using `prependTo`.

It would be better to create a separate div with class `my-filter` using the [dom](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option.

```
dom: "<'row'<'col-md-6 '<'my-filter'>l><'col-md-6 pull-right'>r>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",`
```

And then work with that `<div class="my-filter"></div>` as follows:

```
$("#fr_dd")
   .prependTo(".my-filter")
   .removeClass('hide');
```

See [this corrected example](http://live.datatables.net/laxinabe/14/) for demonstration.